# LINQ where clause returns null

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to get values from xml using LINQ.  When I add where clause I get null.  When I remove the where clause I get items from xml, but there's no property for 'Value'.

This is the xml I'm trying to get BatchId, ResultCode, and SearchId values from.

```
{<WsSearchReply xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ExtensionData />
  <BatchId>6787350</BatchId>
  <Hits />
  <ResultCode>NO_HITS</ResultCode>
  <SearchId>67292500</SearchId>
</WsSearchReply>}

This returns 4 items:
IEnumerable<XNode> dps = from el in d.Root.Nodes()
                              select el;

this doesn't return any records:
IEnumerable<XNode> dps = from el in d.Root.Nodes()
                         where el.Equals("<ExtensionData />")
                         select el;

using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

string text = Serializer.SerializeObject<CchSearchService.WsSearchReply>(reply, true);

XDocument d = new XDocument();
XElement e = XElement.Parse(text);
d.Add(e);

IEnumerable<XNode> dps = from el in d.Root.Nodes()
//where el.Equals("<ExtensionData />")
 select el;

foreach (XNode el in dps)
{
    string x = el.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(el);
}
```

Comment: Is it returning null or just some empty collection now?

Comment: Try `where el.Name.LocalName == "ExtensionData"` instead.

Comment: el is an XNode. you compare XNode to a string.

Comment: where el.Equals("<ExtensionData />") will never find match - it would look for "<<ExtensionData/>>" node

Comment: Also you should do `d.Root.Elements` instead of `Nodes` so you'll have all the element info like the `Name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the ExtensionData elements you can simply use the following:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> dps = d.Root.Elements("ExtensionData");
```

which essentially is a quick way of doing this (you have suggested that you must use lync for this in a comment,  the below code is unnecessary)

```
IEnumerable<XElement> dps = from el in d.Root.Elements() where el.Name.LocalName.Equals("ExtensionData") select el;
```

For further info, an `XElement` implements `XNode`.  `XNode` is the base class and the Nodes enumerable can contain things other than elements such as comments (XComment) and does not have a name.  If you use the `Elements` property you will only return `XElement` objects.  The XElement class contains data relating to an Element eg the Element name

Comment: It still came up null. 
       
XDocument d = new XDocument();
XElement element = XElement.Parse(text);
d.Add(element);

IEnumerable<XElement> dps = from el in d.Root.Elements()
                            where el.Equals("<BatchId/>")
                            select el;

Comment: Just do IEnumerable<XElement> dps = d.Root.Elements("BatchId").  You don't need the from...select it does nothing.  And you are passing in the <.../> you just use the letters "BatchId" not "<BatchId/>" and el.Equals is not the way to check the name anyway.

Comment: and do please mark the above as the answer if it solves your problem.  Thanks

Comment: It really doesn't answer what my initial question was.  I've been trying to learn LINQ to get certain values from xml.  The last comment doesn't do that.

Comment: if you really insist on having linq in there then you would do this:  IEnumerable<XElement> dps = from el in d.Root.Elements() where el.Name == "BatchId") select el;  But its completely unecessary code

Comment: dps is null.
IEnumerable<XElement> dps = from em in d.Root.Elements()
                                 where em.Name.Equals("BatchId")
                                 select em;

Comment: I'd expect it to be an IEnumerable containing no elements but not null.  Anyway you need to do Equals on LocalName:  IEnumerable<XElement> dps = from el in d.Root.Elements() where el.Name.LocalName.Equals("BatchId") select el;